# Getting transpose symbols to be along the same line

Tags: math-mode, vertical-alignment, superscripts

For my expression,

```
\dot{R}(t)R^{\top}(t) + R(t){\dot{R}}^{\top}(t) = 0  
\dot{R}(t)R^\top(t) = -{(\dot{R}(t)R^\top(t))}^{\top}
```

The transpose symbols are not along the same line and this is bugging me. How do I correct this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You abound in braces:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\tran}{^{\top\kern-\scriptspace}}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
\dot{R}(t)R\tran(t) + R(t)\dot{R}\tran(t) = 0 \\
\dot{R}(t)R\tran(t) = -(\dot{R}(t)R^\top(t))\tran
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

I defined `\tran` rather than using `^{\top}` for two reasons:

1. we can reduce the space after it
2. if we change our mind about the symbol for the transpose, we can just modify one definition

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! This did fix my second equation but unfortunately the first is still the same. I'm using mathjax, could that be a problem?

Comment: @KarnikRam MathJax is not TeX and I generally don't expect too much from it.

Comment: Alright thanks! Let me see if there's a work around.

Comment: Easy fix - R(t)\smash{\dot{R}}^{\top}(t)